# Canvas grid squashed when initially loaded, auto adjust to be sqaure grid after resizing the webpage window

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, canvas, grid

When the website is initially loaded, the grid is squashed
[squashed grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DV8S6.jpg)

After resizing the webpage window it auto fixes the problem
[squared grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rVxtU.png), but the grid extends over the webpage

After going into the css, the box-sizing is inherent. If I delete the box-sizing attribute, the grid is fixed.

The following is the css code for the grid.

```
#renderContainer {
    z-index: 0;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;

* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

*, ::before, ::after {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    box-sizing: inherit;
```

The source code can be find on https://github.com/CIDARLAB/3DuF/blob/webpack-build/src/components/Visualiser.vue

The styling code can be find on https://github.com/CIDARLAB/3DuF/blob/webpack-build/public/modified.css

The html can be find on https://github.com/CIDARLAB/3DuF/blob/webpack-build/public/index2.html

Anyone know why this is happening?

Thank you!

Comment: Please include some minimum code which we can run to see the problem for ourselves.As your question stands we'd just be guessing at solutions.